# How to create a primary key on N:M relationship?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am using SQL Server. I have 2 tables.

> 1. Categories
> 2. Skills

Those Tables looks like,

```
| SkillId | SkillName  | CreatedAt  |
=====================================
| 1       | programing | 01/02/2018 |
```

Category Table

```
| Category| CategoryName | CreatedAt  |
=====================================
| 1       | Technical    | 01/02/2018 |
```

---

I have a 3rd Table to map the relationships. It looks like,

```
| CategoryId | SkillId |
========================
| 1          | 4       |
| 2          | 3       |
| 2          | 4       |
```

**My Question is**

What are the right database designing method?

**What I tried**

Do I want to put **Primary Key** for the **3rd Table**. It is something like this ?

```
| RowId | CategoryId | SkillId |
================================
| 1     | 1          | 4       |
| 2     | 2          | 3       |
| 3     | 2          | 4       |
```

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are 2 different RDBMS, which one are you *actually* using? Question like are very "opinionated" as well; Stack Overflow isn't the  place for discussing what is the "best" way to do design something; it's not specific coding questions. If you have a coding question, what is it here?

Comment: The third table should indeed have a primary key: `(CategoryId, SkillId)` I don't see the benefit of adding a generated ID for that

Comment: Time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design. PS It's not clear what you are asking. But if you googled many clear concise statements of your question without your particular strings/names, which you should do before considering asking any question, then you would find that it is a faq. (Maybe it is about whether one should add a unique id column as an extra key to a table. Ie in technical terms adding a surrogate key when there is already a natural key.)

Comment: I guess we should to reopen this question. I have reworded to fit the rules. With this few changes It is a good question asking for a way to create a primary key. How to create a primary key is not a primarily opinion-based question but it is an opportunity to expose the both accepted options: *"natural key"* vs *"surrobate key"*. In my opinion it is a good question.

Comment: @daniherrera The question is still unclear. And if it were clear it would still be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have two approach:

- Natural key: a primary key composed by `CategoryId , SkillId`
- Surrogate key: an `Id` as primary key + `UNIQUE Constraint for CategoryId , SkillId`.

Quoting [Wikipedia surrogate key explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key):

> A **surrogate key** (or synthetic key, entity identifier, system-generated key, database sequence number, factless key, technical key, or arbitrary unique identifier) in a database is a unique identifier for either an entity in the modeled world or an object in the database. The surrogate key is not derived from application data, unlike a natural (or business) key which is derived from application data.

And [Wikipedia Natural key definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key):

> A **natural key** (also known as business key) is a type of unique key, found in relational model database design, that is formed of attributes that already exist in the real world. It is used in business-related columns. In other words, a natural key is a candidate key that has a logical relationship to the attributes within that row. A natural key is sometimes called domain key.

Also,  you can learn about [Unique Constraint at w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp):

> The UNIQUE constraint ensures that all values in a column are different.
>   Both the UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns. A PRIMARY KEY constraint automatically has a UNIQUE constraint. However, you can have many UNIQUE constraints per table, but only one PRIMARY KEY constraint per table.